# MS Outlook email rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I am trying to create a rule which moves emails with words in the subject line. If I create the rule with single criteria the rule woks just fine, but if I create a rule with multiple criteria, i.e. `text 1` or `text 2`, then it does not.

I have identified that the issue lies with the quotes around the text in the "filter".

[image: Screenshot - Text without quotes]

If I create the rule from scratch, then the quotes appear and the rule does not work.

[image: Screenshot - Text with quotes]

How to create a rule with multiple conditions or statements, i.e. `text 1` or `text 2` to create a single rule for all related items, instead of creating a separate rule for each condition or statement?

Comment: The quotes appear to indicate that '***or***' is not part of the phrase being searched for, and that there are 2 phrases being looked for. To differentiate '*rhythm and blues*' from '*rhythm*' AND '*blues*'

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you are trying to search for, and what the rules is that you are trying? Even if hypothetical, it might help to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes is normal when you add multiple criteria:

[image]

Try manually run this rule to see if it works: Click Folder > Run Rules Now.

[image]

If rules don't run automatically, This usually indicates a corruption of either the rule or within the mailbox. It could also indicate a corruption in the send/receive settings file (srs-file) of Outlook.

Resetting the send/receive settings can be achieved by renaming the srs-file of your profile to .old. You can find the srs-file for your mail profile in: 
 C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook

Reference: [rules don't work again](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c64cf52e-b186-441e-bc17-a42b03e1052d/rules-dont-work-again?forum=outlook)

[Rules do not work automatically](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/133)

Comment: I tried, but it does not work.

Comment: If you are using Exchange account, create the rule via web mail to test the results.    Otherwise, run "outlook /cleanrules" in Run to clean all rules and re-configure again. (If you have other important rules, backup them before run this command)